# Ordering records by the presence of a record in join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join

So I have a table of `users` and a table of `departments`. These are joined through another table `department_users`.

I am displaying a grid of users against departments, with a tick if a user is in a department. This is done by checking if a user has an entry in the `department_users` table that joins them to the department.

I now want to sort the records so all those who are in department A are at the top, i.e. the first column of the grid is all ticks at the top, then all crosses at the bottom.

I am familiar with ordering on the value of a database column, but I am not sure how to order by a join record existing for a user.

Edit:

The relationship between users and departments is many to many.

What I really want is

```
User.all ORDER BY (user.departments.includes?  'Department A')
```

so if a user is in department A it is before all the others.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to order the users according to the department:

```
User.joins(:departments).order("department_users.department_id")
```

This will generate the query as:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `department_users` ON `department_users`.`department_id` = `users`.`id` INNER JOIN `departments` ON `departments`.`id` = `department_users`.`department_id` ORDER BY department_users.department_id
```

This will order the users according to the department. Please correct the association names/table names accordingly. They might be wrong.

Edit:

As according to your condition you can do it like this:

```
User.joins(:departments).order("FIELD(department_users.department_id, field_names)")
```

For example:

```
User.joins(:departments).order("FIELD(department_users.department_id, 'Department A', 'Department B')")
```

But remember to mention all the department names don't miss any of them or else it would not work properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't quite what I need. This puts all users with a department at the top, but doesnt group them by a chosen department.